# Store Command to DGI 0202 is giving 6A88 error

Tags: c#, smartcard, emv

**I am trying to personalize below data with my tool but I am getting "6A88" error.**

Below are the personalization of DGI.
Dears Arjun , Please find below complete command from beginning.

**ERROR LOG:**
`Send------> 91023BA539500D5669736120456C656374726F6E8701019F1101019F120D5669736120456C656374726F6E5F2D02656E9F38039F1A02BF0C059F4D020B0A
Response------> 9000`

`Send------> 91041282023C00940C080101001001040018010201`
Response------> 9000

`Send------> 01014F704D57134166390514720355D20122261656381400000F9F1F183136353633303030303030303030303831343030303030305F201A454E434F4445445F303335352020202020202020202020202020
Response------> 9000`

`Send------> 020181B67081B39081B0826E5DE2DA465AD6F14959414D5D672A9B806C8425BCAD154899B973A3A94896E2A4ECFF197C2025AE8315274DE2770787ED9006936B45CDE6F1B176E933FF09A38951804B12E8A5DAA30470FCA97B64E5562E1DA9B90B654BB463BC5E8134A08559641FC78D0A423FCDC1B59460446C8C004CF85956F931C52DD1506BD59DCC12C903B7A57544D0E7666E4E2F9F762189E8ECC827A304DB8429A6C0BCB3F1DD5EB80F1DBAA3846529A392BD448B3984
Response------> 9000`

`Send------> 02023970378F01929224FB1D71CEDE213DB6F40CED0069B2C4E49FA4EF16D9C7701BD1F93E60DB5833EAE7C010219F3201039F4701039F49039F3704
Response------> 6A88`

---

**Successful Log:**

`Send------> 91023BA539500D5669736120456C656374726F6E8701019F1101019F120D5669736120456C656374726F6E5F2D02656E9F38039F1A02BF0C059F4D020B0A
Response------> 9000`

`Send------> 91041282023C00940C080101001001040018010201
Response------> 9000`

`Send------> 01014F704D57134166390514720355D20122261656381400000F9F1F183136353633303030303030303030303831343030303030305F201A454E434F4445445F303335352020202020202020202020202020
Response------> 9000`

`Send------> 020181B67081B39081B0826E5DE2DA465AD6F14959414D5D672A9B806C8425BCAD154899B973A3A94896E2A4ECFF197C2025AE8315274DE2770787ED9006936B45CDE6F1B176E933FF09A38951804B12E8A5DAA30470FCA97B64E5562E1DA9B90B654BB463BC5E8134A08559641FC78D0A423FCDC1B59460446C8C004CF85956F931C52DD1506BD59DCC12C903B7A57544D0E7666E4E2F9F762189E8ECC827A304DB8429A6C0BCB3F1DD5EB80F1DBAA3846529A392BD448B3984
Response------> 9000`

`Send------> 02023970378F01929224FB1D71CEDE213DB6F40CED0069B2C4E49FA4EF16D9C7701BD1F93E60DB5833EAE7C010219F3201039F4701039F49039F3704
Response------> 9000`

Can anyone help me on this issue?
While other tool successfully personalize same data on chip.

Comment: Please share the log of both tools (which return success, and which return failed) from the first APDU until this command. This will help people to analyze what's wrong. Also, if you had success with another tool, why mind using this tool?

Comment: 6A88 means Reference data not found, your command seems fine to me. here you are personalizing tags like 8F,92,9F32 ,9F47 and 9F49. Have you successfully personalized tag 90 - Issuer Public key Certificate??? Could you share the both log for better understanding.

Comment: Did the `STORE DATA` of DGI 0201 before this one work?

Comment: Am I correct that the logs differ only in the error value?

Comment: Yes i am able to personalize 0201 without any error but in both case. In both log the only difference is successful of is for Visa Credit and unsuccessful logs for Visa Electron. I am personalizing same Tags in all DGI for both. Please can anyone help me in this issue.

Comment: chip is same or you are using different chip for credit and electron???

Comment: Do you have any news regarding this question? I am quite curious where the problem was...

Answer (score 2):

EMV CPS 1.1, July 2011, page 11:

> The DGI must be coded on two bytes in binary format, followed by a
>   length indicator  coded as follows:    On 1-byte in binary format if
>   the length of data is from ‘00’ to ‘FE’ (0 to 254  bytes).    On
>   3-byte with the first byte set to ‘FF’ followed by 2 bytes in binary
>   format  from ‘0000’ to ‘FFFE’ (0 to 65 534), e.g. ‘FF01AF’ indicates a
>   length of 431  bytes.

Your length is encoded as in BER TLV.

EDIT>

The offending part is the `DGI 0201`, which *might* be interpreted as being 129 bytes long (i.e. `0201 81 B67081B39081B0....31C5`).

The remaining bytes of this "block" then *might* be interpreted as a start of another DGI: `D150 6B D59DCC....3984` --  which is incomplete, so the remaining bytes of this DGI are expected in the following "block".

Once the complete `DGI D150` is received it triggers the `0x6A88` error.

Note: "block" = `STORE DATA` payload

Comment: thanks for this explaination. you are right DGI command should like 0201B67081B390....84, but there are still a question, why same command is returning 9000 for other. @Faraz could you try to send command without 0x81 (third byte) ???

Comment: @Arjun Maybe different "tools" use a different way to parse data. Maybe different cards/applets...I really don't know. Hope the OP will tell us.

Comment: Dear All,Thanks for giving your valuable time on this issue. but I want to say you that I am using same chip and same script for personalizing only different is as I already mention VISA Electron giving ERROR and VISA Credit is successful personalizing.and i am using same DGI and same tag for personalizing. how it is possible that one data is personalize and other is not.

Comment: Ok, but this _VISA Electron_ and _VISA Credit_ means what (i.e. what is the thing you change for these two)? In your log it is always a _VISA Electron_ (according to DGI 9103 | Application Label).

Comment: Additionally, what happens when you change the `020181B67081B390...` into `0201B67081B390...` as proposed?

Comment: @vlp - You mean DGI 9102 | Application Label -tag 50)

Comment: @Arjun You are right, thank you..the application label is in DGI 9102